# Supporting 3D coordinates in TimescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

Does TimescaleDB support 3D coordinates like `latitude`, `longitude` and `altitude`? In the docs it is said it supports 3D  coordinates, but in an example only `latitude` and `longitude` is used. Please, help me to clear on this.
Also, if its clear written in some document. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension [PostGIS](http://postgis.net) can be installed alongside with [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com). PostGIS supports 3D points, which are created by [ST_MakePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html). Timescale provides a nice [tutorial](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/tutorials/tutorial-hello-timescale#postgis), which shows how to use TimescaleDB and PostGIS together. The tutorial demonstrates usage of 2D, however you can use 3D points instead.

**UPDATE**: 3D types are described in PostGIS docs on [this page](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/3d.html).

Here is an example with using `PointZ` type:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION timescaledb;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

CREATE TABLE t AS (
  time timestamptz not null,
  geom  geometry(pointz)
);
SELECT create_hypertable('t','time');
INSERT INTO t(time, geom) VALUES ('2020-07-21 11:25', ST_MakePoint(2822.6, 33629.8, 41000.0));
```

Comment: @daminichopra I fixed the example with using proper 3D point type, `PointZ`, and gave link to the doc. Now the example should work. Don't forget to accept the answer if it really helps.